# how to make a suggestion of product in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to ask for an opinion on how I want to make a function that shows a product based on [userprofiling database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvzNl.png), For example, if the user has more than 5 values in a certain category it will show the product [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irAhb.png). This is my  [product data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tfIi.png). What I want to do is show the product based on the number of categories on the user profiling database. For example, when the user profiling database has camera:6 and car:6, I want it to show a product that has the category car and camera.

For now, I am only able to show only one category of the product. My question is how can I show multiple categories that have more than five [the example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo6QY.png).

```
 ProfileModel profileModel = ProfileModel();

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('userprofiling')
    .doc(user!.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
      profileModel = ProfileModel.fromMap(value.data());
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    acc = profileModel.accessories!;
    ant = profileModel.antique!;
    cam = profileModel.camera!;
    car = profileModel.car!;
    com = profileModel.computer!;
    fur = profileModel.furniture!;
    game= profileModel.game!;
    lap = profileModel.laptop!;
    men = profileModel.men!;
    moto = profileModel.moto!;
    mus = profileModel.music!;
    pho = profileModel.phone!;
    spe = profileModel.speaker!;
    spo = profileModel.sport!;
    toy = profileModel.toy!;
    tv = profileModel.tv!;
    women = profileModel.women!;
      if(acc > 5){
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Recommendation"),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: StreamBuilder(
                stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').where("categoryP", isEqualTo: "Accessories").snapshots(),
                builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot){
                  if(streamSnapshot.hasData){
                    return GridView.builder(gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                        childAspectRatio: 2/3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 15),
                        itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                          (streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]);
                          DateTime dt = (documentSnapshot['endDateTime'] as Timestamp).toDate();
                          return buildImageCard(documentSnapshot['imageURL'][0], documentSnapshot['nameP'], documentSnapshot['startPrice'], dt, documentSnapshot['id']);
                        }
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
            )
        );
      }
      if(ant > 5){
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Recommendation"),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: StreamBuilder(
                stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').where("categoryP", isEqualTo: "Antique").snapshots(),
                builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot){
                  if(streamSnapshot.hasData){
                    return GridView.builder(gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                        childAspectRatio: 2/3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 15,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 15),
                        itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                          (streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]);
                          DateTime dt = (documentSnapshot['endDateTime'] as Timestamp).toDate();
                          return buildImageCard(documentSnapshot['imageURL'][0], documentSnapshot['nameP'], documentSnapshot['startPrice'], dt, documentSnapshot['id']);
                        }
                    );
                  }
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
            )
        );
      }
}
```

For my code, I just call the data and insert it into the model and call it, I know my method is wrong for it to get to show the multiple categories, for my code it will only show one category

```
Future<String> downloadURL(String images) async{
    url = await st.ref('products/$images').getDownloadURL();
    // for(int i = 0; i<images.length; i++){
    //   url.add(await st.ref('products/${images[i]}').getDownloadURL());
    // }
    return url;
  }
 Widget buildImageCard(String image,String name,String price, DateTime dt,String id) => FutureBuilder( future: downloadURL(image),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)  {
      if(snapshot.hasData){
          return Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Ink.image(
                      image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => DetailScreen(
                                productId: id,
                              )));
                        },
                      ),
                      height: 170,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4).copyWith(bottom: 0),
                      child: Text(
                        name,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // SizedBox(height: 3),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6).copyWith(bottom: 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "RM $price",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6),
                Expanded(
                  child: CountDownText(
                    due: dt,
                    finishedText: "The Auction has End",
                    showLabel: true,
                    daysTextShort: "D ",
                    hoursTextShort: "H ",
                    minutesTextShort: "M ",
                    secondsTextShort: "S ",
                    style:
                    TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.lightGreen),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 2),
              ],
            ),
          );

          }

      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );

    },
  );
```

And here is my widget to show the image from firebase storage

```
class ProfileModel{
  int? accessories,antique,camera,car,computer,furniture,game,laptop,men,moto,music,phone,speaker,sport,toy,tv,women;

  ProfileModel({this.accessories,this.antique,this.camera
    ,this.car,this.computer,this.furniture,this.game
    ,this.laptop,this.men,this.moto,this.music,this.phone
    ,this.speaker,this.sport,this.toy,this.tv,this.women});

  factory ProfileModel.fromMap(map){
    return ProfileModel(
      accessories: map['accessories'],
      antique: map['antique'],
      camera: map['camera'],
      car: map['car'],
      computer: map['computer'],
      furniture: map['furniture'],
      game: map['game'],
      laptop: map['laptop'],
      men: map['men'],
      moto: map['moto'],
      music: map['music'],
      phone: map['phone'],
      speaker: map['speaker'],
      sport: map['sport'],
      toy: map['toy'],
      tv: map['tv'],
      women: map['women'],
    );
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    return {
      'accessories': accessories,
      'antique': antique,
      'camera' : camera,
      'car': car,
      'computer': computer,
      'furniture': furniture,
      'game': game,
      'laptop': laptop,
      'men': men,
      'moto': moto,
      'music': music,
      'phone': phone,
      'speaker': speaker,
      'sport': sport,
      'toy': toy,
      'tv': tv,
      'women': women,

    };
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>{
    'accessories': accessories,
    'antique': antique,
    'camera' : camera,
    'car': car,
    'computer': computer,
    'furniture': furniture,
    'game': game,
    'laptop': laptop,
    'men': men,
    'moto': moto,
    'music': music,
    'phone': phone,
    'speaker': speaker,
    'sport': sport,
    'toy': toy,
    'tv': tv,
    'women': women,
  };

  static ProfileModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=> ProfileModel(
    accessories: json['accessories'],
    antique: json['antique'],
    camera: json['camera'],
    car: json['car'],
    computer: json['computer'],
    furniture: json['furniture'],
    game: json['game'],
    laptop: json['laptop'],
    men: json['men'],
    moto: json['moto'],
    music: json['music'],
    phone: json['phone'],
    speaker: json['speaker'],
    sport: json['sport'],
    toy: json['toy'],
    tv: json['tv'],
    women: json['women'],

  );



}
```

this is my ProfileModel

Comment: please include some codes too

Comment: I have included the code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are parsing the data but you don't have to check every key like how you created it. you can do something like this

```
List.generate(profileModel.length, (index){
  if(profileModel[index] > 5)
  {
    return buildImageCard();
  }else{SizedBox.shrink();}
});
```

Comment: I have already updated the details, about my problem and I hope you can help me with it

Comment: Yeah it's the solution for your query. Instead of using the category key i used the index. And checked the length and returned a card if it's over 5

Comment: for the profileModel.length, it shows The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'ProfileModel and profileModel[index], it shows The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'ProfileModel'. and how do I control the snapshot() in StreamBuilder so that it will only show the product that has a category above 5

Comment: I am unable to build your code since it has data from firebase. Just to give you an overview. Your have added profileModel = ProfileModel.fromjson. But if you directly use var jsonDecoded = json.decode(snapshot.data) you can use jsonDecoded[0] to access the first element in snapshot

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new in flutter so I don't understand how to use jsonDecoded, can you explain, how do I use jsonDecoded based on my code

Comment: Got it. Don't worry everybody is learning. Please check json serialisation in flutter. You will get a better idea of how to use the data from api. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json